# Encrypt text using RSA public key

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to implement the RSA encryption algorithm in which ios app will encrypt the data using RSA public key and send it to the server and server will decrypt it using RSA private key.

The problem is with the encryption, I don't have the public key file, it resides server-side. The server is sending the public key in the form of NSString. So the question is - How I can convert the NSString (public key) to RSA Public Key?

So far I have followed this link - http://jslim.net/blog/2013/01/05/rsa-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypt-it-using-php/

I've used the following command to generate the key pair and certificate request:

```
openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der
    -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

Comment: What format of RSA Public Key are you trying to get?

Comment: This question is too broad, either add details of what you have tried and what is not working or search [ios NSString public key](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+NSString+public+key+is%3Aquestion) existing questions.

Comment: @reecon : I have got the .der public key file and .pem private key file by executing the openssl command - `openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650`

Comment: Please edit the additional information into the question, don't put it in a comment. Seems to me you've got a certificate request instead of a public key. The request may *contain* the public key, but that does not mean it *is* one.